# string operation in node

Tags: node.js, string, cookies

I have a string

```
a = 'w=9090;a=111;b=222'
```

and a new string

```
b = 'a=333;c=234'
```

How can I get `'w=9090;a=333;b=222'` in node(koa)? Is there any third party packages can do this?

(Actually, I'm replacing the cookie with new fields to get a new cookie string, but not setting a new cookie.)

Comment: Can't you just use `str.replace()` for this?

Comment: Can't you use some library to parse the cookie and update its value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a library for this. Looks too specific. Here's a small piece of code that does that for you.

```
var a = 'w=9090;a=111;b=222',
b = 'a=333;c=234';
b = b.split(';').reduce(function(p, c) {
   var t = c.split('=');
   p[t[0]] = t[1];
   return p;
}, {});
a = a.split(';').map(function(v) {
   var t = v.split('=');
   return b[t[0]] ? t[0] + '=' + b[t[0]] : v;
}).join(';');
console.log(a);
```